# jquery: merge two files: jquery.searchable.js with page1.html

Tags: jquery, merge, external

jquery: merge two files:  jquery.searchable.js with page1.html

Hi.
Thi is  [page1.html](https://pastebin.com/ZsCPVqBJ).
This is [jquery.searchable.js](https://pastebin.com/edit/BFwuayLh) .

I want "copy and paste" the code of jquery.searchable.js, into page1.html.
I want one only html file.

---

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>page1</title>


<script>
//INVOKE THE SCRIPTS AND PASS ARGUMENTS
$(function () 
{
    
    $( '#searchable-container' ).searchable({
        searchField: '#container-search',
        selector: '.row',
        childSelector: '.col-xs-4',
        show: function( elem ) {
            elem.slideDown(100);
        },
        hide: function( elem ) {
            elem.slideUp( 100 );
        }
    })
});
</script>
</head>
<body> <!--SOME HTML CODE--></body></html>
```

```js
//jQuery Searchable Plugin v1.0.0


;(function( $, window, document, undefined ) 
 {
   //SOME JAVASCRIPT CODE
 })( jQuery, window, document );
```

Comment: Then do it. What error are you getting?

Comment: @pedro. Ok, now works. Thanks. This is the final file https://pastebin.com/YDfwxzTt